# Assymetric encryption using crypto and Decrypting using OpenSSL php

Tags: javascript, php, encryption

Is it possible to do assymetric encryption using crypto js and then Decrypting it using open ssl PHP.

I have the following code which encrypts data in JS.

```
const crypto = require("crypto");
const fs = require("fs");

function encrypt(toEncrypt) {
  const publicKey = fs.readFileSync("../keys/public_key.pem", "utf8");
  const buffer = Buffer.from(toEncrypt, "utf8");
  const encrypted = crypto.publicEncrypt(publicKey, buffer);
  return encrypted.toString("base64");
}

module.exports = {
  encrypt,
};
```

Then, I would like to decrypt data using PHP open SSL, which I cant seem to do.

This is what I have tried. Based on my research, openssl doesn't support SHA-256 only SHA-1. What would the alternative be ?

```
<?php



function decrypt($data) {
    $privateKey = file_get_contents("../keys/private_key.pem");
    $kh = openssl_pkey_get_private($privateKey);
    var_dump($privateKey);
    $result = openssl_private_decrypt($data, $r,  $privateKey,OPENSSL_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING);
    var_dump($result); //returns false
}
?>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, OpenSSL supports SHA-256, see [this method](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-get-cipher-methods.php) for what PHP can access. You encryption is base64 encoding the output, and I’m not seeing you perform the opposite before decrypting

Comment: @ChrisHaas Thank you Sir. I forgot to decode and add in Padding.

Comment: *...openssl does not support SHA-256, only SHA-1...* This is at least misleading in this generality. What is correct is that PHP/OpenSSL does not support SHA-256 **for OAEP**, but only SHA-1.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I solved it I forgot to add in Padding & decode my $data in the openssl_private_decrypt method.

Here is the full code

```
    //Encryption
    const crypto = require("crypto");
    const fs = require("fs");
    
        
   function encrypt(toEncrypt) {
              const publicKey = fs.readFileSync("../keys/public_key.pem", "utf8");
              const buffer = Buffer.from(toEncrypt, "utf8");
              const encrypted = crypto.publicEncrypt(publicKey, buffer);
              return encrypted.toString("base64");
            }
```

Whereas to decrypt in PHP

```
//Decrypt

<?php



function decrypt($data) {
    $privateKey = file_get_contents("../keys/private_key.pem");
    $key = openssl_get_privatekey($privateKey);
    $data = base64_decode($data);
    $result = openssl_private_decrypt($data, $decrypted, $key,OPENSSL_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING);
    if ($result) {
        # code...
        $decrypted_data = base64_decode($decrypted);
        return $decrypted_data;
    }
    return "No data";
}
```

Thank you.